# Why is "flag 5" of this code getting skipped? Why isnt the if statment running?

Tags: java, conditional-statements

so what I made here is a toString() method for 3d vectors. For example, if the ThreeDVector had components, x = 1, y = 1, z = 1. Then you run the toString() method, as shown in the main method at the bottom of this code. Then its supposed to print out, "i + j + k", but it only prints out "ijk", without the operaters. This is not the only problem, if you see how I added flag statements, after every if and else statement, some of them do not run at all. For example if you were to trace through the code, and you keep, "x = 1, y = 1, z = 1," in mind, then "Flag 5" is supposed to run?? The conditional statement before "Flag 5", states, "if(x != 0). That is true, because x = 1 in this scenario, and its supposed run that if statment and print out "Flag 5", but it just skips it?? I don't understand this much, I would be grateful if you could help out, thanks!

```
public class ThreeDVector
{
@Override
public String toString() 
{
 double x = this.x;
 double y = this.y;
 double z = this.getZ();

 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 //x =1 , y = 1, z = 1
 if (x != 0)//true 
 {
  if (x != 1)//false
  {
   System.out.println("Flag 1");
   sb.append(roundThreeDecimals(x) + "i");
  }
  else//true
  {
   System.out.println("Flag 2");
   sb.append("i");
  }
 }
if (y != 0)//true
{
 System.out.println("Flag 3");
 if (y != 1 && y > 0)//false
 {
  System.out.println("Flag 4");
  if (x != 0)//true (not working???)
  {
   System.out.println("Flag 5");
   sb.append("+" + roundThreeDecimals(y) + "j");
  }
  else
  {
   System.out.println("Flag 6");
   sb.append(roundThreeDecimals(y) + "j");
  }
 }

 else if (y != 1 && y < 0)
 {
  System.out.println("Flag 7");
  sb.append(roundThreeDecimals(y) + "j");
 }
 else
 {
  System.out.println("Flag 8");
  sb.append("j");
 }
}
if (z != 0) 
{
 System.out.println("Flag 9");
 if (z != 1 && z > 0) 
 {
  System.out.println("Flag 10");
  if (y != 0 || x != 0)
  {
   System.out.println("Flag 11");
   sb.append("+" + roundThreeDecimals(z) + "k");
  }
  else
  {
   System.out.println("Flag 12");
   sb.append(roundThreeDecimals(z) + "k");
  }
 }

 else if (z != 1 && z < 0)
 {
  System.out.println("Flag 13");
  sb.append(roundThreeDecimals(z) + "k");
 }
 else
 {
  System.out.println("Flag 14");
  sb.append("k");
 }
}
 return sb.toString();

}


//This main method will test the toString() method

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  ThreeDVector d = new ThreeDVector(1,1,1);

  System.out.println(d.toString());//this is supposed return i+j+k, but it only returns ijk

}
}
```

Comment: Ctrl + F formats your code in most IDEs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would 'flag 5' need to run? The `if` at flag4 doesn't, because y *is* 1, therefore `y !=1 && y > 0` is false, thus the entire block, starting at `print flag 3` and ending at the `if (z != 0)` line is skipped entirely. The expression isn't even evaluated - it's in a code block that isn't run at all.

Those flags indicate you're trying to debug this code, so you're doing what you're supposed to. I'm therefore not sure what to tell you for future endeavours; asking on SO every time you run into trouble doesn't seem like a sustainable practice. Perhaps take out pen and paper and follow through each if statement exactly, matching what you think should happen with what is actually happening (and those print statements should let you figure out what is actually going on). There where what you think doesn't match with what happens, you found a bug, and probably also where to look to fix this bug. Keep doing that, perhaps a bit more deliberately next time.